# What is IDENTITY_INSERT and MERGE in SQL Server? 

Tags: c#, sql-server, merge

Anyone explain me the what is the use of `MERGE`?

```
MERGE Dev.dbo.ProductTypeGroup AS target
USING (
        SELECT * FROM Staging.dbo.ProductTypeGroup
    ) AS src
    ON 
        target.ProductTypeGroupId = src.ProductTypeGroupId
```

Comment: These are two entirely separate questions and answers to both of them are easily found in SQL Server Books Online. [`IDENTITY_INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx), [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Comment: you don't show any research effort...you just pasted the code here for someone else to solve the issue for you entirely..this is not how things work around here...see the FAQ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Dev.dbo.ProductTypeGroup ON
```

This means that you allow inserts of values in the identity column, instead of relying on SQL Server supplying an identity value for you.

[MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522.aspx) is used to perform an atomic UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE based on some criteria (otherwise you would have to lock the rows in a transaction while checking for the preconditions - which in some cases can be hurtful for performance)

What the statements you posted in their entirety do is to transfer all rows from the table `ProductTypeGroup` on database `Staging` to the same table in database `Dev`. After running this SQL, `Dev.dbo.ProductTypeGroup` will contain the exact same as `Staging.dbo.ProductTypeGroup`, including the identity values (and hence the need to set `IDENTITY_INSERT` on).

Comment: Note to anyone finding this answer: the question was edited after I posted; there was more code originally, doing a full merge between the two tables mentioned.